# macOS High Sierra - Why are only some characters in this SVG able to be found or browsed (searching with CTRL+F) using Firefox or Safari?

Tags: macos, firefox, svg, browser, safari

I reproduced this bug on two different computers (both running macOS High Sierra). On one of them, I performed a clean install Mozilla Firefox for the first time, just to test this bug. The version of Firefox Used was 61.0.1.

Please behold [the following SVG](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/55/Group_structure_and_statistics_of_%E2%80%9CGourmet_Master_Co._Ltd.%E2%80%9D%2C_as_of_31_December_2017_-_%E3%80%8C%E9%96%8B%E6%9B%BC%E7%BE%8E%E9%A3%9F%E9%81%94%E4%BA%BA%E8%82%A1%E4%BB%BD%E6%9C%89%E9%99%90%E5%85%AC%E5%8F%B8%E3%80%8D%E7%9A%84%E9%9B%86%E5%9C%98%E6%9E%B6%E6%A7%8B%E5%8F%8A%E7%B5%B1%E8%A8%88%EF%BC%8C%E6%88%AA%E8%87%B32017%E5%B9%B412%E6%9C%8831%E6%97%A5.svg) published [at Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Group_structure_and_statistics_of_%E2%80%9CGourmet_Master_Co._Ltd.%E2%80%9D,_as_of_31_December_2017_-_%E3%80%8C%E9%96%8B%E6%9B%BC%E7%BE%8E%E9%A3%9F%E9%81%94%E4%BA%BA%E8%82%A1%E4%BB%BD%E6%9C%89%E9%99%90%E5%85%AC%E5%8F%B8%E3%80%8D%E7%9A%84%E9%9B%86%E5%9C%98%E6%9E%B6%E6%A7%8B%E5%8F%8A%E7%B5%B1%E8%A8%88%EF%BC%8C%E6%88%AA%E8%87%B32017%E5%B9%B412%E6%9C%8831%E6%97%A5.svg).

A lot of strangeness is going on with this.

---

When I browse for the string:

- *and*

I get

- `1 match` on Safari; i.e. I can only reach **1 of the 5 matches**; and
- on Firefox, if I press `Highlight All` it correctly highlights the 5 instances, but I can only toggle from `1 of 5 matches` through `1 of 3 matches` before getting the statement `Reached end of page, continued from top`. In other words, using the up and down arrows that would normally focus through the results, I can only reach **3 of the 5 matches**.

---

When I browse for the string:

- *公司*

I get

- `47 matches` on Safari; i.e. I can reach all, i.e. **47 of the 47 matches**; and
- on Firefox, if I press `Highlight All` it correctly highlights the 47 instances, but I can only focus on one instance, namely `35 of 47 matches` before getting the statement `Reached end of page, continued from top`. In other words, using the up and down arrows that would normally focus through the results, I can only focus on  **1 of the 47 matches**.

---

When I browse for the string:

- *這一鍋*

I get

- `1 match` on Safari; i.e. I can reach all, i.e. **1 of the 1 matches**; and
- on Firefox, if I press `Highlight All` it correctly highlights the 1 instance, but I can not focus on it, I only get the statement `Phraase not found`. In other words, using the up and down arrows that would normally focus through the results, I can focus on  **0 of the 1 matches, which is not even recognized as a match**.

---

If you don't believe me, I can make a screen capture and upload it as a GIF. My question is: why is this behavior occurring and how to fix it?

Peers on other operating systems have informed me that they were unable to reproduce this bug (one on Windows tried using Firefox and another peer on Gentoo Linux also tested on Firefox).

Comment: This seems to be a software question of the kind you might ask on Super User rather than a programming question.

Comment: Per your advice, **[migrated to Super User (link here)](https://superuser.com/questions/1338347/macos-why-are-only-some-characters-in-this-svg-able-to-be-found-or-browsed-se)**.